# Долго устанавливается соединение с БД

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Стало очень долго проходить соединие с БД (примерно от 10 секунд до 1 минуты).   Причем, когда связь установлена, запросы выполняются быстро.  Запрос статуса Listener иногда может выполниться за секунду, а иногда висит по 3 минуты. Такое поведение началось примерно вчера. Саму машину с сервером несколько раз перезагружали, но никакого эффекта это не принесло. Подозрительных сессий и программ не найдено.

Проблема, судя по всему, как раз в долгом соединении с Listener. В настройках *tnsnames.ora* и *listener.ora* пробовали указывать доступ через IP и через доменное имя, но ничего не помогло.

Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Comment: На вопрос _Как можно исправить_, можно ответить, когда будет понятно, что надо исправить. Если вчера работало, а сегодня нет, то это значит, что что-то изменилось в этот промежуток времени. Что вы уже предприняли, чтобы найти причину задержек, или найти то, что конкретно изменилось со вчера на сегодня в системе, сетевой конфигурации и тд?

Comment: В конфигурациях в это время ничего не менялось,  в системе тоже. Единственное,  утром, я дала права некоторым пользователям  GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO USER, но табличного пространства было достаточно на момент последнего просмотра сегодня. Проблема в Listener, соединение через него стало долго обрабатываться.  На некоторых форумах  советовали почистить логи Listener, но они создаются каждый день и имеют максимальный размер 10МБ.

Comment: Вы единственное лицо во всей организации, кто может что-то изменить в системе и сетевой конфгурации? Что стоит в последних логах прослушивателя? Прослушиватель единственный на БД или есть удалённые прослушиватели? tnsping также с задержкой? Сам сервер с БД "здоровый", htop, df, syslog посмотрели?

Answer (score 3):

Дело было все же в большом размере файла с логами Listener.

На то, что причина в Listener указывало то, что очень долго устанавливалось соединение и очень долго отрабатывал tnsping (иногда > 20сек). После установки соединения сами запросы выполнялись быстро.

Методом гугления симптомов выяснилось, что  чаще всего такое поведение вызывается большим размером файлов логов.

Сам файл нашли просто перебором всех файлов с расширением .log, он имел имя listener.log и был больше 4ГБ (система 32-ух битная).

Файл логов пересоздали. Отключили на время логирование в Listener: добавили `LOGGING_LISTENER = OFF`  в файл listener.ora и перезагрузили Listener.

Comment: Ответ будет более полезным, если вы дополните его подробностями. Как быстро определить, что логи "выросли"? Что такое "большой", 1мб, 1гб, 1тб? Как измениить уровень логгирования, чтобы исключить переполнения логов в будущем?